# All browsers loading external js files( http://netloader.cc/run.js, http://p.chango.com/static/c.js)

Tags: javascript, browser, yslow

when I open any website or local website in any browser Its loading some unknow js files. `http://netloader.cc/run.js`, 
`http://p.chango.com/static/c.js`

Because of these js files I am not able to get exact page size by using Yslow. Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: having the exact same issue.  hope someone knows what the heck those 2 are, b/c google isn't providing much.

Comment: in firefox, i'd somehow gotten the extension: VideoFileDownload - Download Youtube Videos 1.5 removing this caused yslow to no longer detect those scripts.

Answer (score 5):

I got rid of the p.chango.com script by going to their website and clicking "opt out." 
It does not appear to be a very dangerous script but does track your searching and 
browsing for "target marketing purposes."

I removed an unknown extension "SelectionLinks 1.5" and that got rid of netloader.cc. 
It appears to be attached to a number of extensions so just look for the ones you don't
know what they do. Personally I am blocking all content from their host server at 
205.234.175.175. If you do the same tell the parent company at www.cachefly.com.

The trustworthy extension "noscript" is very good at blocking these scripts as well as
letting you know the sneaky buggers are there in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

i fixed it, it seems there is a plugin named "videodownload" belong to youtube in chrome, just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, wasn't quite able to fix it, but at least this is a workaround:

1. Open up your host file (on windows 7 it's under C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc) and add the following:
   127.0.0.1       netloader.cc
2. Restart your browser and force refresh any pages you've visited (to clear out the run.js cache

Comment: +1 HOSTS file is a pretty good workaround for stuff like this. Thing is, where there's one malware, there's quite often another, and the only *real* solution is to reformat and reinstall a fresh copy of the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Its a Malware.

Go to Start->Control panel->Add/Remove Programs, try to remove the software named videoDownload or something similar which you have not installed recently.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: +1 I did not even know I had this software installed, anyways this solved my problems guys.

Answer (score 0):

Searching Google, it looks like both of those are either malware and/or suspicious tracking scripts. For example search for "netloader.cc/run.js" or "chango.com malware" to see several results along with removal instructions.

It's likely that either your browser(s) have some extensions which have been installed, or the computer itself is infected.

Comment: I have scanned my PC and its using McAfee anti virus software. But it didn't detect any virus. Still its loading those js files. Please help me out guys...to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Chrome, through an extension called "*Select links app 4.3* (select words and get links)". Disabling it stopped the message exchange with Chango.com. I think it came from an application I installed through **cnet.com** (at download.cnet.com)

Answer (score -1):

If you installed MKV File Player, that will also load 2 other programs that will put this on.

Sorry I can't remember the names of the 2 programs, but just go to Control Panel, Remove Programs, sort on "Installed On" column, and you'll see the 2 others right next to MKV File Player.